# how to send a multicast message to couple of peers in C windows

Tags: c++, c, udp, winsock, multicast

i'm writing a program in C for windows that has to send messages to couple of peers, each with different IP and port. no need to guarantee the delivery of the messages. so i'm looking to send a multicast message not limited to same LAN that i'm on.

How do i do it ? do i have to send each message separately to each of the peers or is there an option to send to to everyone without iterating ?

Do i need to open a socket connection to each one of the peers ?

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Hi Michael, how do you know the peers will be listening?  What mcast address will they register to for this applicaiton?

Comment: Hi Mike, i can assume the peers are listening on a listen_port that is known to me, but again, i don't need to guarantee the delivery of the message. i'm not familiar with mcast socket at all, i wanted to know the right msdn functions to use and the usual workflow of the process - eg open a socket, bind it to a port etc...

Comment: Michael, multicast is very different than unicast in the way it works... Since your clients may not even be on the same LAN segment with your server, they need to register with `IGMPv2` or `IGMPv3` so the network infrastructure knows who to deliver the multicast to.  Furthermore, if the mcast messages are sent through routers, your IT team will need to configure that (usually they  do it on switches too... normally that's not as important), if it's not already there.  I'm not a windows programmer, so I can't comment on windows-specific issues.

Comment: Are you sure you need multicast here? Looks like you just need to send the same data to different peers ie. use multiple "unicast" streams. You are going to have connection overhead, etc if you need to use TCP. If you use UDP instead, you should be able to address your reqt (no-guaranteed delivery of same data to multiple receivers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common ways to do this.

### UDP Unicast

You maintain a list of IP address receivers in your program, iterating over each receiver and sending a copy of every datagram to each receiver.

### IP Multicast

The list of receivers has to exist somewhere. If you use IP Multicast, then the list of receivers is maintained by your networking equipment, usually a router or layer-3 switch. Enable Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMP) in your router, and then the receivers can send IGMP join requests to the router to add themselves to a multicast group. A multicast group is defined as an IP endpoint -- an IP address and a port. In IPv4, addresses 224.0.0.0 through 239.255.255.255 are designated as multicast addresses. To send a datagram to all of the members of the multicast group, just send the datagram once by UDP Unicast to the multicast group endpoint. The router will then forward the datagram to all members of the group.

If the receivers are not on the same LAN as you, you probably won't be able to use IP Multicast. IP Multicast will only work if you can know in advance the network route for all receivers who may join your multicast group, and make sure that all the network equipment is configured properly.

You can't use IP Multicast over the internet.